# PDO insert fails when field name and value contains single quote (42000/1064)

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

When a PDO for MySQL prepared statement has :

- parameters (`v = ''`)
- a field with name containing a single quote (`f'f`)
- `VALUES` part with parameter followed by a value with
  single quotes (`''`)

then it failes with an exception :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':v,'')' at line 1
```

Some code to reproduce :

```
function query($sql) {
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...', 'u', 'p', [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ]);
   $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(['v' => '']);
}

query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f'f`,`f`) VALUES ('',:v)"); // ok
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f`,`f'f`) VALUES ('',:v)"); // ok
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f'f`,`f`) VALUES (:v,'')"); // exception
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f`,`f'f`) VALUES (:v,'')"); // exception

query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f'f`,`f`) VALUES (null,:v)"); // ok
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f`,`f'f`) VALUES (null,:v)"); // ok
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f'f`,`f`) VALUES (:v,null)"); // ok
query("INSERT INTO `t` (`f`,`f'f`) VALUES (:v,null)"); // ok
```

PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24, mysqlnd 5.0.11

Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

---

**Update:**

Tried on PHP Version 7.1.15-1, mysqlnd 5.0.12 : no changes.

Tried with positional parameters : no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted column names are not a problem for MySQL. I can test successfully using the MySQL client (no PHP at all):

```
mysql> set @v = '';

mysql> set @sql = "INSERT INTO `t` (`f'f`,`f`) VALUES (?,'')";

mysql> create table t (f int, `f'f` int);

mysql> prepare stmt from @sql;

mysql> execute stmt using @v;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+------+------+
| f    | f'f  |
+------+------+
|    0 |    0 |
+------+------+
```

The fact that the error comes from MySQL, and it sees the named parameter placeholder `:v` is a problem. MySQL doesn't support named parameter placeholders natively, so PDO should have substituted a positional parameter with `?`.

So if there's a bug, it's in PDO. I suspect PDO is getting confused about the single-quote in your column name, as it tries to parse the SQL string for parameter placeholders.

I recommend that you don't use column names containing single-quotes when using PDO.

PHP 5.5 is quite old, it has been [out of support for almost two years](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (I'm writing this in March 2018). These days, should be using at least PHP 7.1.

I suggest you repeat your test with PHP 7.1 and see if the bug in PDO has been fixed. Also try your test with positional parameters (using `?` placeholders) to see if it gets around the problem.

Comment: Updated question following your suggestions with no change. So I suppose it's a PDO problem.